# Passing a variable from Php dropdown list to Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I've got a form (id="my_form_id") and inside the form I have Dropdown list populated using PHP and a query from a Mysql, this mysql query pick the column named grupo and populated the dropdown list, the mysql table field named nombregrupo is put and updated (onchange) in a "input text" named nombregrupo using the Java script function "showname". I've got a  text (named "nombregrupon") for typing and changing field nombregrupo. 
I want to send the information selected from drop down list (field grupo) and typed in the  text (named "nombregrupon") to ajax jquery function, and this ajax function calls a php file (postdata.php) for processing a returning data back to ajax.

I can pass the information entered in the  text (named "nombregrupon") to ajax function but I cannot pass the information from dropdown list (grupo) to ajax function, this is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}

</script>

//Java script function for updating input text nombregrupo
<script language="JavaScript">
function showname(what)
{
  what.form.nombregrupo.value=what.options[what.selectedIndex].title
}

window.onload=function() {
  showname(document.form1.grupo)
}
</script>


//Ajax Jquery for send data variables grupo and nombregrupon to php
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#my_form_id').on('submit', function(e){
                    //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var nombregrupon = $('#nombregrupon').val();
          var grupo= $('#grupo').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'postdata.php',
            data: { grupo: grupo, nombregrupon: nombregrupon },
                        success: function(data){
                            //Send Alert
                            alert(data);
                            //Show data returne from php postdata file
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>



</head>

<body>
<form id="my_form_id" name="form1">
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysq1passw0rd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("llamadas", $con);

//PHPMysql Query for fill dropdown list
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM grupostroncales ".
"WHERE grupo!='$grupox' ORDER BY grupo";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

//On change call java script funtion for update Input text nombregrupo
echo "<select name=\"grupo\" onchange=\"showname(this)\">";

while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
echo "<option value=\"$row1[grupo]\" title=\"$row1[nombregrupo]\">$row1[grupo]</option>";

}

echo "</select>";// Closing of list box 
?>
//Input Text for showing group Name
<input name="nombregrupo" type="text" id="nombregrupo"/>
//Input Text for entering new group Name
<input name="nombregrupon" type="text" id="nombregrupon" />  
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Acept" />
<div id="result"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a PHP dropdown list.  There is a HTML drop down list (commonly a select element).  It may seem like schematics but by the time JS runs PHP has finished what it needs to do and has sent the page source code to the client.  So the question is how to get the value of a select element and use that in Ajax

Comment: In this case `$('select[name="grupo"]').val()`  So you need to add `data: { grupo : $('select[name="grupo"]').val() }` to the AJAX call. Or you can serialize the entire form.  `data: $('#my_form_id').serialize()`

Comment: As to why it's not working now is that this id `var grupo=$('#grupo').val()` doesn't exist on the select element `echo "<select name=\"grupo\" onchange=\"showname(this)\">";`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

You can add the id to the select element, as you forgot that

```
var grupo=$('#grupo').val()
echo "<select name=\"grupo\" onchange=\"showname(this)\">"; <-- no id
//----------------
echo "<select id=\"grupo\" name=\"grupo\" onchange=\"showname(this)\">";
```

or You can use the name

```
var grupo=$('select[name="grupo"]').val()
```

or You can serialze the whole form

```
$.ajax({
 data : $('#my_form_id').serialize(),
 ...
});
```

Personally I would just serialize the form

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again, I modified the code addind "select id" and It worked.

Please, Now I'm trying to pass the whole form variables using serialize but I doesn't work, this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}

//Fir
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function showname(what)
{
  what.form.nombregrupo.value=what.options[what.selectedIndex].title
}

window.onload=function() {
  showname(document.form1.grupo)
}
</script>

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              var Formvar = $('#my_form_id');
              $("#submit").click(function(){
                     $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:Formvar.attr("action"),
                        //url: 'ActualizarGrupoTroncalb.php',
                        data:Formvar.serialize(),
                        success: function(data){
                            //Send Alert
                            alert(data);
                            //Show data from mysql query
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>



</head>

<body>
<form action="ActualizarGrupoTroncalb.php" id="my_form_id" name="form1">
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysq1passw0rd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("llamadas", $con);

//Hago query1 selecciono el Departamento a buscar
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM grupostroncales ".
"WHERE grupo!='$grupox' ORDER BY grupo";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<select id=\"grupo\" name=\"grupo\" onchange=\"showname(this)\">";

while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){//Array or records stored in $nt
echo "<option value=\"$row1[grupo]\" title=\"$row1[nombregrupo]\">$row1[grupo]</option>";

}

echo "</select>";// Closing of list box 
?>
<input name="nombregrupo" type="text" id="nombregrupo"/>
<input name="nombregrupon" type="text" id="nombregrupon" />  
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Acept" />
<div id="result"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@lexer, in regards to your second question, you may want to try `.serializeArray()` instead of `serialize()`.

`.serialize()` returns a string of values formatted like a query string and that may not be what you are expecting.

FYI - I would have commented to the post but I cannot comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code and variables are serialized to php file: ActualizarGrupoTroncalb.php and recieved for php file because I can make a mysql query using variables, but returning data from php to ajax is not show in: `<div id="resp"></div>`

This my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}


</script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function showname(what)
{
  what.form.nombregrupo.value=what.options[what.selectedIndex].title
}

window.onload=function() {
  showname(document.form1.grupo)
}
</script>

   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).on('ready',function(){

      $('#submit').click(function(){
        var url = "ActualizarGrupoTroncalb.php";                                     

        $.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: url,                    
           data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
           success: function(data)            
           {
             $('#resp').html(data);           
           }
         });
      });
    });
    </script>



</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="formulario">
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysq1passw0rd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("llamadas", $con);

//Hago query1 selecciono el Departamento a buscar
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM grupostroncales ".
"WHERE grupo!='$grupox' ORDER BY grupo";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<select id=\"grupo\" name=\"grupo\" onchange=\"showname(this)\">";

while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){//Array or records stored in $nt
echo "<option value=\"$row1[grupo]\" title=\"$row1[nombregrupo]\">$row1[grupo]</option>";

}

echo "</select>";// Closing of list box 
?>
<input name="nombregrupo" type="text" id="nombregrupo"/>
<input name="nombregrupon" type="text" id="nombregrupon" />  
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Acept" />
</form>
<div id="resp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```